# How can I color braces in showexpl?

Tags: listings, showexpl

I want to use `showexpl` and have the LaTeX code printed with colored braces. I can do this within a `lstlisting` environment by adding a literate option like in the example below, but not within a `LTXexample` environment (it produces an error). Is there a way to have the braces colored in the code block of a `LTXexample` environment?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{showexpl}
\lstset{language=[LaTeX]Tex,texcsstyle=*\color{red}}

\begin{document}
\begin{LTXexample}
\textit{Test}
\end{LTXexample}

\begin{lstlisting}[
    literate=
        *{\{}{{\textcolor{blue}{\{}}}{1}
        {\}}{{\textcolor{blue}{\}}}}{1}
]
\textit{Test}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image: example of colored braces]

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 8):

Because `showexpl` is based on the `listings` package, most of the latter's features, including the `literate` key should, in theory, work out of the box. For some reason, though, defining the literal replacements globally, like so

```
\lstset
{
  literate=
    *{\{}{{\textcolor{blue}{\{}}}{1}
     {\}}{{\textcolor{blue}{\}}}}{1},
}
```

seems to break `showexpl`, which complains about an `Undefined control sequence \textitTest`. I don't know the innards of `showexpl` well enough to have a good explanation for that error, but it seems that the braces get dropped when they shouldn't. It looks like a bug in `showexpl` to me, especially because the the inception of the `literate` key in `listings` (1999) predates the first release of `showexpl` (2004).

One workaround is to define those literate replacements, not globally, but within a custom style; you shouldn't get any error, then.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{showexpl}

%% returns an error!
%\lstset
%{
%  literate=
%    *{\{}{{\textcolor{blue}{\{}}}{1}
%     {\}}{{\textcolor{blue}{\}}}}{1},
%}

\lstdefinestyle{myLaTeX}
{
  language=[LaTeX]Tex,
  texcsstyle=*\color{red},
  literate=
    *{\{}{{\textcolor{blue}{\{}}}{1}
     {\}}{{\textcolor{blue}{\}}}}{1},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{LTXexample}[style=myLaTeX]
\textit{Test}
\end{LTXexample}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=myLaTeX]
\textit{Test}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```