# Highlighting a backslash with showexpl or listings

Tags: listings, showexpl

Is there a way to highlight a single backslash (`\`) within LaTeX code with `listings` or `showexpl`?
In the following example, `\LaTeX` is correctly highlighted, but not the following backslash.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,showexpl}
\lstset{language=[LaTeX]Tex,
   basicstyle=\ttfamily,
   keywordstyle=\color{red},
   texcsstyle=*\color{blue}
   }

\begin{document}

\begin{LTXexample}
Test \LaTeX\ test
\end{LTXexample}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436) and thanks for providing a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228).

Answer (score 4):

See also [How can I color braces in showexpl?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166424/how-can-i-color-braces-in-showexpl)

The problem is that `showexpl`, `texcl`, `moretexcs`, `morekeyword`, and `literate` are not compatible in some ways. So just try out everything you think of.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{xcolor,showexpl}
        \lstset{language=[LaTeX]Tex,basicstyle=\ttfamily,texcsstyle=*\color{blue}}
        \lstdefinestyle{myLaTeX}{literate={~}{\textcolor{blue}{\char`\\\char`\ }}2}
\begin{document}
    \def~{}
    \begin{LTXexample}[style=myLaTeX]
        Test \LaTeX~test
    \end{LTXexample}
\end{document}
```

This also works, with wrong spacing. (I am using `U+00A0`, the non-breaking space. But there is an ascii-space before `test`)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,showexpl}
    \lstset{language=[LaTeX]Tex,basicstyle=\ttfamily,texcsstyle=*\color{blue}}
    \lstdefinestyle{myLaTeX}{moretexcs={ }}
\begin{document}
    \def\ {}
    \begin{LTXexample}[style=myLaTeX]
        Test\LaTeX\  test
    \end{LTXexample}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have the same problem, except I don't need the backslash to be colored. Is there an easier/better way to get the "char`\ " character after the backslash in this case.

Comment: @Gaussler Do you mean ``\char`\\\textcolor{blue}{\char`\ }``?

Comment: No I need no colours at all. Is there a less "hacky" solution in this case?

Comment: @Gaussler Consider ``literate={~}{\char`\ }}1``, where `~` can be replaced by any other character you want, even `U+00A0`. In case you want a *global replacement*, checkout `showspaces=true,showtabs=true`.

Comment: Why does it only work when I use `\lstdefinestyle`, not when I put it into `\lstset`?

Comment: @Gaussler It is known that sometimes `\lstdefinestyle` and `\lstset` are not equivalent. This issue had appeared several times on TeX.SX but, if I recall correctly, no one can tell why. Feel free to ask a new question if necessary~~